# Customize DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have an list of objects I like to display in a DataGrid.

```
int LocationId { get; set; }
string LocationName { get; set; }
ProductionArea Area { get; set; }
DateTime CreateDateTime { get; set; }
string DropFolderPath { get; set; }
string CreateBy { get; set; }
int Plant { get; set; }
```

But I also need some extra fields to show progress in each row ore checkbox to check if action is needed. But also like to not show all fields, like for example "LocationId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will have to set `AutoGenerateColumns=false` on your DataGrid and create columns for your data. You can create as many columns and bind to the only data you want to display

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding LocationName}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

For showing ProgressBar in column, you can use DataGridTemplateColumn and define a CellTemplate for it to have ProgressBar.

Comment: Is it not possible to work from the same list, so i dont have to split it up?

Comment: yes.. you just need to bind the itemsSource of grid to list of objects you added in your question.. but by setting AutoGenerateColumns="False" you can decide that which columns you want to have in your DataGrid and to which property they should bind to